# Identifying message type when parsing Outlook .pst file using pypff

Tags: python, parsing, outlook, pst

I'm trying to write a Python-script for parsing .pst-files from Outlook using pypff. I've successfully extracted all the information I need, except from the message type. This is important, as I want to be able to distinguish between ordinary e-mails, meeting invitations and other items in the file.

Distinguishing between object types seems to be possible in the libpff (ITEM_TYPE), but this functionality does not seem to be implemented in pypff.

Does anybody have an idea how to extract this information from a .pst-file, either using pypff or some other handy Python package?

Answer (score 1):

All messages are grouped into folders (default and user-defined) in the pst file. Default folders like Inbox, Outbox, Sent Items, Deleted Items, Drafts, Tasks, Contacts can be used to differentiate pypff message objects.